# Is this a rip off of the " General Electric " logo?

Tags: logo, critique

Velo company is a company that deals with vapors and they come to me and ask to design a logo that contain drops of water and a sense of movement.

First I create a " V " letter and in the negative space I integrate a drop of water.

Second I integrate a sense of movement with those drops of water combined with that circle.

So tell me, is this a rip off of the " General Electric " logo ?

[image]

[image]

And if you have suggestions to improve the design will be very much welcomed.

Comment: Ahh is a Vape company - do they make ecig and cannabis vapes?
I just found their old logo - very wispy, but with similar elements... is the shape part of the mechanics of the device?

Comment: No the shape is not the mechanic of the device but they want to integrate a sense of movement and somehow integrate something relate to water.I develop few more ideas for this project.All of my ideas come first from sketching.

Comment: Regardless of if it would result in legal issues (IANAL, but I don't think so...), it would still confuse people brand-wise which isn't good for a logo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my money.. it's too close.

While it may not have been a direct copy or even on your mind when creating the Velo logo, what you've come up with is very similar to the GE circle. If I were GE, I would be asking the legal department if we should do anything.

Comment: The logo was not chosen yet by the client.

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: I think its a crowd source design

Comment: Oh, it's a contest (yuck, yuck, yuck)... well I wouldn't expect to win with something so close to the GE logo.

Answer (score 3):

Very subjective, but if it was me, I would stay clear and find some other idea to follow. I would not take the chance, simply.

Answer (score 0):

I would move on and come up with other concepts. The circle and water droplets are very similar in nature.

Answer (score 0):

Not only the logo but also the color make them too much ressemblant.

If I had to produce a logo for, let's say, a boat company and designed a siren and made it white on a green background, there's no way Starbuck wouldn't feel ripped off.

This is confusing as the average consumer wouldn't tell the difference immediatly and if the two companies had similar activities, it would even be prone to a legal action.
This said, I am not a lawyer either.